# TemplateDoesNotExist: polls/question_detail.html Django tutorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Studied the tutorial up to the seventh part. Everything was fine until I decided to launch my application. After launch, I added a multiple choice question. The error occurs after I click on a question to answer it. Long searches for an answer did not bring any results. Please help.

*I get this error:*

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/1/
polls/question_detail.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/
Django Version: 4.0.dev20210118085850
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
polls/question_detail.html
Exception Location: c:\users\mrand\django\django\template\loader.py, line 47, in select_template
Python Executable:  C:\Users\mrand\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\mrand\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\mrand\\Anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\mrand\\Anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\mrand\\Anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\mrand\\Anaconda3\\envs\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\mrand\\Anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\users\\mrand\\django',
 'C:\\Users\\mrand\\Anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\mrand\\Anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\mrand\\Anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Wed, 27 Jan 2021 01:15:15 +0300
```

*Traceback:*

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/

Django Version: 4.0.dev20210118085850
Python Version: 3.8.6
Installed Applications:
['polls.apps.PollsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\mrand\mysite\templates\polls\question_detail.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\mrand\mysite\polls\templates\polls\question_detail.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: c:\users\mrand\django\django\contrib\admin\templates\polls\question_detail.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: c:\users\mrand\django\django\contrib\auth\templates\polls\question_detail.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mrand\django\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "c:\users\mrand\django\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "c:\users\mrand\django\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "c:\users\mrand\django\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "c:\users\mrand\django\django\template\response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "c:\users\mrand\django\django\template\loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/1/
Exception Value: polls/question_detail.html
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
# Leave the rest of the views (detail, results, vote) unchanged
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Question
# ...
def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import Question
# ...
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question
# ...
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

 
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    ... # same as above, no changes needed.

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

**Settings.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-&6_7o3ob-kr=@!hoyu&-&8t8+t7r5_-9ejnz4lrehwvwd5=i+a'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

#TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Update**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Jis.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Django is searching for the template named `question_detail.html` in these directories:

```
C:\Users\mrand\mysite\templates\polls\question_detail.html

C:\Users\mrand\mysite\polls\templates\polls\question_detail.html 

c:\users\mrand\django\django\contrib\admin\templates\polls\question_detail.html

c:\users\mrand\django\django\contrib\auth\templates\polls\question_detail.html
```

and it can not found.

Make sure you put your **template in the right place**. If nothing changed, try to **rename** your template name from `polls/detail.html` to `polls/question_detail.html` in your view:

```py
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/question_detail.html', {'question': question})
```

```py
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/question_detail.html'
```

**Updated**
Depending on your dirs, pretty sure the problem is because of `DIRS` setting in `settings.url`. Change `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`, to `'DIRS': [],`

Comment: This is my directoris https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Jis.png

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is because of  `DIRS` setting in `settings.url`. Change `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],` to `'DIRS': [],`

Comment: Thank you very match)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the pk is not 1.Also in the actual version of django you do not need to declare the template folder as it will be automatically used for it

Answer (score 0):

in django it is a good practice to respect the paths, if you have un app called polls then it is a good idea have

```
root_project
    ...
    polls
        templates
            polls
               all your templates here for you polls app
    ...
```

with this structure you can use in your views

```
....
return render(request, 'polls/your_template.html', {})
....
```